# How to enable virtualization, Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox on Windows 10?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, virtualization, docker

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 in a VirtualBox on a Windows 10 machine.

I'm trying to create and test a Docker swarm by creating a couple virtual machines on my (virtual) Ubuntu OS. (I know, I know. VMs on VMs on VMs. I should just get a Mac). I've downloaded VirtualBox in Ubuntu, and am running the following at command-line:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
```

Which returns:

> Running pre-create checks... Error with pre-create check: "This
>   computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is
>   mandatory"

Virtualization is enabled on my Windows 10 machine:

[image: Task Manager Performance Sccreenshot]

Virtualization also appears enabled for Ubuntu, as viewed through the VirtualBox Settings (running on Windows):

[image: Ubuntu Virtualization Settings]

I've tried to enable through the Ubuntu BIOS on startup, but I can't seem to get in there to change anything. If I press F2 or F12 or ESC (or any key for that matter), I can see a list of processes running during startup, but don't have any control, and the OS just boots as normal. Ancillary question, is there a BIOS for Ubuntu running on a VM, or just one for my hardware?

I read that perhaps I should disable Fast Startup on my Windows machine, and have done that, but have seen no difference. And my host machine boots up pretty fast anyway, too.

UPDATE:

If I run in Ubuntu Terminal,

```
grep --color vmx /proc/cpuinfo
```

nothing is returned. Same for svm, which would appear to confirm that virtualization is not enabled or possible. The ultimate question is, how do I enable it?

Comment: Read the error message carefully: You need to boot into BIOS and simply enable that BIOS setting. On your hardware running your Win 10 host.

Comment: thanks @ user535733. If i'm running a virtual machine on my Win 10 host, doesn't that indicate I have virtualization enabled? See above update.

Comment: No: Hardware virtualization is a *performance* feature, not a *security* feature. You can run virtualization in software without enabling any hardware features...it's merely much less efficient to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want virtualisation INSIDE the guest then you need to enable that in the virtualbox settings.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/nested-virt.html

[image]

If you wanted something else then perhaps you can clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

My setup is similar yours and I encountered the same error. The following code fixed the issue for me.

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check myvm1
```

Here's a link where I found it. https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports nested virtualization on **virtualbox version 6.0** and onwards but only for host systems that run AMD and Intel CPUs.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/nested-virt.html